# Using QGIS to plot locations on map of US by zip code?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.2

I am new to QGIS.  I just installed QGIS 2.2 on my MAC Airbook with Mavericks.

How do I simply plot a few locations on a map of the US?

All of the tutorials I can find on the web are for older versions.  Version 2.2 seems to be entirely different in terms of look and feel.  For example, one tutorial tells me to load the plugin "edit any layer".  Under 2.2 no such plugin seems to exist. I simply need to know how to get map loaded and then how to plot some excel or CSV data.

Answer (score 3):

In QGIS 2.2 there is under the Layers menu, "Add delimited text layer". The window that opens allows you to browse to find your csv file, and choose the columns that contain the X and Y coordinates. After clicking OK you need to also choose what coordinate system the points are referenced in (hint: Long/Lat degrees using the WGS84 datum is EPSG code 4326). And the points appear on the map canvas.